# Python 2.7 Quitting

Tags: python, quit

I've added in this function which makes sure the user actually wants to quit the program. It works when you actually want to quit but if you want to return to the program it just loops the statement:

```
def WantToQuit():
    Quit = raw_input("Please enter y if you are sure you want to quit, if not press n to return ")
    if Quit == 'y':
        print ('')
    elif Quit == 'n':
        DisplayMenu()
        return WantToQuit()
```

Elsewhere:

```
elif Choice == 'q':
    WantToQuit()
    raw_input('Press enter key to continue ')
```

Comment: Is there a reason for your `WantToQuit()` function to call itself recursively?

Comment: you should really indent your code, so we can at least know where that return statement or the second raw_input belong

Comment: I just realised i called it twice, what function should i return at the end??

Answer (score 5):

Replace `print ('')` with `sys.exit (0)` with and remove the `return WantToQuit()`.

I would also recommend that you apply `.lower()` on your `Quit` variable so that it is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to show you what you're doing wrong without more code, but here's how I figure you have it setup:

```
def WantToQuit():
    Quit = raw_input("Please enter y if you are sure you want to quit, if not press n to return ")
    if Quit == 'y':
        print ('')
    elif Quit == 'n':
        DisplayMenu()
    return WantToQuit()

while(True):
    DisplayMenu()
    # Some logic to get input and handle it
    # For example, something like
    selection = raw_input("Please make a selection: ")
    if(selection == "1"):
        doSomething()
    elif(selection == "2"):
        doSomethingElse()
    elif(selection == "q"):
        WantToQuit()
    else:
        # TODO: Handle this !
        pass
```

This is how I would do it:

```
def WantToQuit():
    Quit = raw_input("Please enter y if you are sure you want to quit, if not press n to return ")
    if Quit == 'y':
        return true
    elif Quit == 'n':
        return false
    else:
        # TODO: Handle this !
        pass

while(True):
    DisplayMenu()
    # Some logic to get input and handle it
    # For example, something like
    selection = raw_input("Please make a selection: ").lower()
    if(selection == "1"):
        doSomething()
    elif(selection == "2"):
        doSomethingElse()
    elif(selection == "q"):
        if(WantToQuit()): break
    else:
        # TODO: Handle this !
        pass
```

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
def WantToQuit():
    Quit = raw_input("Please enter y if you are sure you want to quit, if not press n to return ")
    if Quit == 'y':
        sys.exit(0)
    elif Quit == 'n':
        return # Do nothing really
    else:
        # TODO: Handle this !
        pass

while(True):
    DisplayMenu()
    # Some logic to get input and handle it
    # For example, something like
    selection = raw_input("Please make a selection: ").lower()
    if(selection == "1"):
        doSomething()
    elif(selection == "2"):
        doSomethingElse()
    elif(selection == "q"):
        WantToQuit()
    else:
        # TODO: Handle this !
        pass
```

The first example has the `WantToQuit` function return a boolean whether the user *actually* wants to quit.  If so, the infinite loop is broken and the program naturally exits.

The second example handles the exiting inside the `WantToQuit` function, calling `sys.exit()` to exit immediately.

The first is probably preferable, although both are used in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a new function, you can use an already defined function called `quit()`. The `quit` function will pop up a box that says:

[In]

`quit()`

[Out]

```
Your program is still running!
Do you want to kill it?
    Yes    No
```